# Whitelabel Error Page Spring boot and AWS RDS

Tags: java, spring-boot

New to using spring boot and keep getting Whitelabel Error Page about mapping

The application.yml I Believe is okay, to be honest I don't what the problem is.

I did generate the entities classes through the generate entities classes from database in NetBeans.

I have my controller, DOA, and entity classes.

Its an API for an android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the console when it spring boot starts and see which endpoint are open for GET method. Also you can try changing the server.port=9095 and check if the whitelabel error page still persist.

Comment: this displayed expected html in browser. Any thoughts on why this fixed things?